# tensorflow :No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I tried to install tensorflow with the version of GPU , but always failed.

Computer system: win 10 professional

Graphics Card : Nvidia Quadro M2000M (I verify this card in Nvidia official website ,it can support CUDA )

My installation process :

1-  install Rapid Environment Editor

2-  install DXSDK_Jun10.exe

3-  install cuda_8.0.61 \ patch 2 and CUDNN5.1

4-  install Visual Studio 2015 community

And then ,I test the example in VS2015.

[image]

5-  install Anaconda 4.4(I also try the vision-4.2,but it is nothing to use)

6-  Create a conda environment  named tensorflow and install the python3.5

7-  Activate the conda environment and install the GPU version of tensorflow

```
pip install --ignore-installed –upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Until I finished these steps , I didn’t receive any error notice, but when I input “import tensorflow as  tf”, it notice me that:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\Vincent>python
Python 3.5.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 14 2017, 13:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have already edit the environment variable as follow:

(maybe the environment have some trouble?)

\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\

\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\sitepackages\tensorflow\python__pycache__\

\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\

\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__pycache__\

\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\

**Anyone has any idea what is the problem is and how to fix it. Thanks a lot**

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing Version 1.3.0 you need to use cuDNN 6 not 5.1. If you followed the instructions on the website then that might be why you're having the error as it's mistakenly listing 5.1 as the cuDNN version. But this issue is being tacked here if you're interested: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11784

If you are still having issues then run this script and let me know the response. I will edit my answer to suit. -->
[mrry's Self-check Script](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c)